# SWIFT - delegates and protocols

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

I need some help in identifying the issues in this code. I think I am trying to do some thing silly here. 
I am creating a class (advertisement class) which will load advertisements in my app. I am trying to use swift delegates, so that when the advertisements are loaded successfully, I can call the function in my main class to display the advertisements. The issue I face here is the actual delegate methods (bannerDidFinishLoading, didFailToLoadWithError ...)  for this advertisement class are not called. I think it was deallocated after the method returned, and this is why the delegate methods were not called. 
In the logs if you notice, none of the delegates for the banner ads is called from advertisement class, but the logs do show the ads were fetched and loaded successfully.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

advertisement.swift:

```
import UIKit
import InMobiSDK
import AdSupport

let INMOBI_BANNER_PLACEMENT2: Int64 = 111111111

protocol bannerViewDelegate:class {
    func bannerViewCalled(banner: IMBanner?)
}

class advertisement: UIViewController, IMBannerDelegate {

    var banner: IMBanner?

    weak var delegatex: bannerViewDelegate?

    func loadBanner() {
        print ("Inside Load")
        banner = IMBanner.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50), placementId: INMOBI_BANNER_PLACEMENT2)
        banner?.delegate = self
        banner?.load()
        banner?.shouldAutoRefresh(true)
        banner?.refreshInterval = 45
    }

    deinit {
        print("Deinit Called")
    }


    public func bannerDidFinishLoading(_ banner: IMBanner!) {
        print("bannerDidFinishLoading")
        delegatex?.bannerViewCalled(banner: banner!)
    }


    public func banner(_ banner: IMBanner!, didFailToLoadWithError error: IMRequestStatus!) {
        print("didFailToLoadWithError")
    }

    public func bannerWillPresentScreen(_ banner: IMBanner!) {
        print("bannerWillPresentScreen")
    }

    public func bannerDidPresentScreen(_ banner: IMBanner!) {
        print("bannerDidPresentScreen")
    }

    public func bannerWillDismissScreen(_ banner: IMBanner!) {
        print("bannerWillDismissScreen")
    }

    public func bannerDidDismissScreen(_ banner: IMBanner!) {
        print("bannerDidDismissScreen")
    }

}
```

Main Class calling advertisement class:

```
import UIKit
import InMobiSDK
import AdSupport

class sample: UIViewController, bannerViewDelegate, IMBannerDelegate {

    var bannerx: IMBanner?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //bannerx?.delegate = self

        print("before call")
        let obj1 = advertisement()
        obj1.delegatex = self
        obj1.loadBanner()
        print("after call")

    }

    func bannerViewCalled(banner: IMBanner?) {

        print("return delegate")
        let tabBar_MinY: CGFloat!       // Starting poition of tab bar
        tabBar_MinY = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.minY
        let adView = UIView()
        adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tabBar_MinY - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 50)
        bannerx = banner
        adView.addSubview(bannerx!)
        self.view.addSubview(adView)
    }

}
```

Logs in console:

```
before call
Inside Load
after call
[InMobi] | 2020.01.26 12:37:34.147 | 1004 |  Fetching banner ad for placement id: 111111111
Deinit Called
[InMobi] | 2020.01.26 12:37:34.926 | 1001 |  Loading Banner ad for placement id: 111111111
[InMobi] | 2020.01.26 12:37:34.929 | 1001 |  Banner ad successfully fetched for placement id: 111111111
[InMobi] | 2020.01.26 12:37:34.998 | 1001 |  Started loading Banner ad markup in the webview for placement id: 111111111
[InMobi] | 2020.01.26 12:37:35.563 | 1001 |  Successfully loaded Banner ad markup in the webview for placement id: 111111111
```

Comment: Move `let obj1 = advertisement()` out of the `viewDidLoad` method and make it an instance variable instead (like `bannerx`).

Comment: @PhillipMills -- it did work. I moved it out of viewDidLoad and made it an instance variable( let obj1 = advertisement())... thank you.  Can you let me know what was the difference between these 2, why it did not work when i had it in viewDidLoad... I would like to learn, so i don't make similar mistakes in future.

Comment: If you define a variable local to a function, you can't depend on it existing after the function ends.  An instance variable lasts as long as the object/(instance) exists.  Since you were supplying it as a delegate, you needed it to stay around after the view was loaded.  (Delegates are frequently held as weak references.)